# Setting an Image to ImageView dynamically

Tags: java, android, imageview, dynamically-generated

Please forgive me if this is a duplicate post but I tried and could not find anything on this subject.
I have a blank ImageView in a layout and now I want to put an image there dynamically. Since there is

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txt.setText("my text");
```

is there a way to do it for an ImageView like the way you would do it for a TextView?

ie...

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.pPicture);
image.setImage(R.drawable.myImage); // I know this isn't correct.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage);
```

or

```
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage);
```

Comment: don't use setBackgroundResource, use setImageResource.  setBackgroundResource is for a background image, you can use that if you have a foreground iamge with transparencies.

Answer (score 1):

```
image.setImageResource(int resId)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display an image file on the phone, you can do this:

```
private ImageView imgView;
imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("pathToImageFile"));
```

If you want to display an image from your drawable resources, do this:

```
private ImageView imgView;
imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageFileId);
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid every problem you can use the sure way

```
Resources res = getActivity().getResources();
 Drawable drawable= res.getDrawable(R.drawable.myImage);
 image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```